# MariaDB - Can't find innodb_log_file_size

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I'm currently installing OTRS on Raspbian. I got it working with Ubuntu and MySQL, but its giving me problems with Raspbian and MariaDB.
I cant seem to find the `innodb_log_file_size` anywhere to change the size of it.

My my.cnf looks like this:

```
The MariaDB configuration file

The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.

If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.

One can use all long options that the program supports.
Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
--print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.


This group is read both both by the client and the server
use it for options that affect everything

[client-server]
 Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

and using `show variables like 'innodb_log_file_size';` in mariadb gives me this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'innodb_log_file_size';
+----------------------+----------+

| Variable_name        | Value    |

+----------------------+----------+
| innodb_log_file_size | 50331648 |
+----------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Any tips to change it? Because I need to get rid of the error:

> "Error: Please set the value for innodb_log_file_size on your database
>   to at least 256 MB"

Answer (score 2):

You say there is a "problem" and an "error"; please provide the text of the error and/or other clues.

50M is a decent size for `innodb_log_file_size`.  It can be set in the `[mysqld]` section of my.cnf.

For very busy systems, it should be higher; for `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns over 5MB in size, it should be higher.  But for most systems, 48M is plenty big.

The setting is one of the hardest to change, so don't without a good reason.

Once you have been running for some time, compute

```
 ( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written )
```

to seem how many minutes between log rotations.  1 hour is a reasonable target.

Comment: This helps but doesn't answer at all the question that is: Where is the innodb_log_file_size configuration in the file set?. This seems to be a comment more than answer or should be edited.